# How to break a Map in Scala and save the key at breakpoint

Tags: scala

So I have a nested map in scala `Map[Int, Map[String, Double]]` and need to iterate over the outside map and for each int have to check if keyset of inner Map contains a particular string. if not i have to break at that point and return the key other f outer map at which the contains failed

E.g.

```
  myMap = Map( (1, Map ("a" -> 13.0,"b" ->12.0 )),(2, Map ("a"-> 12.0, "b"-> 13.0)), (3, Map ("a" -> 11.0,"c" ->12.0 )),(4, Map ("e" -> 11.0,"d" ->12.0 )))
```

I want the first occurrence where inner map doesn't have key = b
So basically my output for above should be 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A good option is to use `collectFirst`:

```
myMap.collectFirst { case (k, v) if !v.contains("b") => k }
```

This returns `Option[Int]` which gives `Some(3)` in your example. It will be `None` if the test fails for all elements in the map

---

This is the solution for the additional question in your comment:

```
val testKeys = List("a", "b", "c").toSet

myMap.collectFirst { case (k, v) if !v.keys.forall(testKeys.contains) => k }
```

This gives `Some(4)`

Answer (score 1):

> I need to iterate over the outside map and [...] break at that point

Map is a collection and has [`.find()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#find(p:A=%3EBoolean):Option[A]):

> Finds the first element of the collection satisfying a predicate, if any.

(Note that "elements" of maps are tuples `(key, value)` and you need `_2` to get to the inner map).

The predicate inside is

> check if keyset of inner Map contains a particular string

That's [`.contains()`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/Map.html#contains(key:K):Boolean).

> Tests whether this map contains a binding for a key.

Putting it together and adding `_1` to get the key which failed the inner map test:

```
myMap.find(_._2.contains("particular string")).map(_._1)
```

Comment: ok Thankyou got that but now if instead of searching for a particular string i want to check if my inner keyset is a subset of a certain list of strings. say i have myList = ("a","b","c") and if the inner keyset is not subset of this list i want to break and display the key at which it broke

Comment: What did you try, and what did you get?

Comment: i mapped the Map[Int,Map[String,Int]] to Map[Int,Boolean] in which the later map value strings are just true or false depending on whether it is a subset or not. The i use find on the new map to find the first occurrence of false and then display the key this works correctly but the whole myMap is iterated and that is reducing the performance like what if false occurs at 2nd key but i have 100,000 entries

Comment: `find` returns an `Option` not a tuple, so that final `_.1` gives a compiler error.

Answer (score -1):

You can use dropWhile

```
val myMap = Map(
  (1, Map ("a" -> 13.0,"b" ->12.0 )),
  (2, Map ("a"-> 12.0, "b"-> 13.0)),
  (3, Map ("a" -> 11.0,"c" ->12.0 )),
  (4, Map ("e" -> 11.0,"d" ->12.0 )))

var missingValue = myMap.dropWhile(_._2.contains("b")).headOption
```

Comment: It is very wasteful to check the whole map and then just take the first value. Also, that bare `head` will fail if there is no matching element found; use `headOption`

Comment: Agree, but in some cases I am willing to compromise simpler solution

Comment: How is this simpler than `collectFirst`?